# Does Adobe Reader on Android support search-by-whole-word?

Tags: pdf, search, acer-iconia-a500, adobe-reader

I have an Acer Iconia Tab.

I would like to search some PDFs ([RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/) reference documents) for "whole words", as normal search doesn't properly find short words.

Is it possible with the [Adobe Reader on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.reader)? If so, how?

(Note: I just updated it a few days ago, and I can't seem to find any such option.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe Reader does not seem to have that feature.

Why not try [ezPDF Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=udk.android.reader)? It supports whole word searches.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that was an excellent recommendation. ezPDF seems faster than Adobe Reader too.